# Filter specific parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I know that I can filter parameter with

```
config.filter_parameters << :password
```

but if I need to filter specific parameter from specific model, for example:

I have models `Customer{name,  address, phone}` and `Supplier{name,  address, phone}` but I need filter ONLY `:address` for `Supplier`

Can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by passing a string of the parameter to filter parameters prefixed with the model name like below

```
config.filter_parameters << 'supplier.address'
```

You can see what the middleware is doing here [Action Dispatch Filter Parameters](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Http/FilterParameters.html)